# Reset DEV branch and copy all files

Tags: git, gitlab

I'd like to reset dev branch on my repository. And I'd like to copy all files from master to dev.

How does it works ?

With these commands it doesn't work :

```
git checkout dev    // swith to dev branch
git merge --no-ff master     // merge from master to dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `dev` to be exactly similar as `master`, unless you're in a context where you can't rewrite `dev`'s history (i.e. you're working in a team where these things are discouraged/forbidden for any reason), one of the simplest ways is to just force your branch to point where you want :

```
# from any branch
git branch -f dev master
```

(You'll then need to `git push -f origin dev` to force update the remote reference.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out your develop branch

```
git checkout dev
```

Reset develop to master

```
git reset --hard master
```

Force push develop to remote (because of history rewrite that happens with reset)

```
git push --force origin develop
```